# How to set background image to activity layout using Picasso Library in android

Tags: android, picasso

I am using picasso library to load images from server. I can set background image to ImageView using Picasso. But I could not set background image using same. I have also try different method to set Image to activity layout background. Plaese help me.

My code is as follows:

```
 
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg").into(new Target() {
```

@Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loginLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using setBackgroundDrawable instead of setBackground

```
@Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loginLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Target

```
Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                activityLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    };
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(target);
```